# Insert data into Umbraco Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, umbraco7

Is it possible to insert data into an Umbraco Grid programmatically?
I am currently inserting content into an RTE field, by setting `Properties["bodyText"].Value = "my new value"` which works fine.

But, instead of the RTE field, i need to insert the content into a Grid layout, containing an RTE field.
The propertyalias for the grid, is `bodyTextGrid`.

Any ideas? (I am using Umbraco 7.7.8)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by manually building a JSON string: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/87899-umbraco-populate-grid-layout-with-rich-text-using-the-contentservice